# How do I get these to all print on the same line?

Tags: python

```
def driving_cost(driven_miles, miles_per_gallon, dollars_per_gallon):
    dm = miles_per_gallon / dollars_per_gallon
    gc = driven_miles / dm
    return gc
    
gas_efficiency = float(input())
gas_cost = float(input())
    
print("{:.2f}".format(driving_cost(20, gas_efficiency, gas_cost)))
print("{:.2f}".format(driving_cost(75, gas_efficiency, gas_cost)))
print("{:.2f}".format(driving_cost(500, gas_efficiency, gas_cost)))
```

Where would I place end = ' ' to get them to print on the same line?

Comment: So, you know about the `end=` parameter. What have you tried?

Comment: I'm really struggling on where to place the parameter...

Comment: I think this should work. print("{:.2f}".format(driving_cost(20, gas_efficiency, gas_cost)),end=" ")

Comment: So, you've tried to use it. Please update your question with your attempts.

Comment: If you've tried to use `end=`, but got it wrong, please show it because there are likely to be future programmers who make the same mistake and might be able to find this question.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want them all on the same line, a more effective approach might be to have a single format string and pass three values to `format`.

```
print("{:.2f} {:.2f} {:.2f}".format(
  driving_cost(20, gas_efficiency, gas_cost), 
  driving_cost(75, gas_efficiency, gas_cost), 
  driving_cost(500, gas_efficiency, gas_cost)
))
```